# Can entropy consumption at program start be prevented?

Tags: linux, kernel, security

I use Knoppix (or other Live CDs/DVDs) as a secure environment for creating valuable crypto keys. Unfortunately entropy is a limited resource in such environments. I just noticed that each program start consumes quite some entropy. This seems to be due to some stack protection feature that needs address randomization.

Nice feature but completely useless and - worse - destructive in my scenario. Is there any possibility to disable this feature? I would prefer one that allows me to continue using the original Knoppix (or whatever) image and just need some configuration at runtime.

I read that this was caused by glibc. I am surprised that an `strace -p $PID -f -e trace=open` against bash does not show any accesses to /dev/random when I start programs. But I am not familiar with the interaction of execve() and the linker.

Comment: You could always invest in a hardware encryption card.

Comment: "completely useless" = actually a security feature universal to modern operating systems... Ps. the kernel does this, so there is no userspace -> system call to trace.

Comment: [ASLR calls `get_random_int`](http://justanothergeek.chdir.org//2010/02/no-more-alsr-bypass-on-linux-2630/). [`get_random_int`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.8.6/drivers/char/random.c#L1471) has [changed several times](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/log/drivers/char/random.c) but I [don't see it depleting the entropy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271589/aslr-affected-by-entropy-available-on-linux). What kernel version did you notice this on? What architecture? Is the kernel compiled with `CONFIG_ARCH_RANDOM`?

Comment: By the way, [Linux's `/dev/random`'s entropy fetishism is misplaced](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key/3939#3939). If there's enough entropy in the system, `/dev/urandom` is fine for key generation, and does not consume entropy.

Comment: @jordanm I do have smartcards but this is not for me. I give (free) courses for OpenPGP beginners and offer key generation because hardly any beginner would get this right by himself. Thus I make them do this within Knoppix. http://www.openpgp-schulungen.de/ (German only though so not useful / interesting for everyone)

Comment: @goldilocks Be honest when you quote: "[...] completely useless [...] in my scenario"

Comment: @Gilles This is Knoppix 7.0.4, 3.4.9 (i686). Unfortunalely there is no `/proc/config.gz` thus I cannot tell the status of `CONFIG_ARCH_RANDOM`. Any other way? About fetishism: This is not about passwords. GnuPG does not only take entropy from `/dev/random` it takes about 20 times as much as is needed for the key material. If you want to discuss that with the crypto nerds on gnupg-devel@: Have fun!

Comment: Hauke, you could try with one of several projects to derive entropy from the LSB of the audio signal (on most systems, you do not even need to plug a microphone in).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If this is indeed due to address randomization (ASLR has to do with where the program is loaded, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) then you can disable it by passing `norandmaps` to the kernel in the boot options (see here: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/kernel_configuration/re30.html).

Comment: This kernel parameter indeed solves the problem.